# Many instances of my aspect are being created outside spring container and properties aren't being injected

Tags: java, spring, aspectj, spring-aop

I have created an aspect to be launched on `@AfterThrowing` exception that has an @Autowired property.

I use the following code:

```
@Scope("singleton")
@Component
@Aspect
public class NotificationAspect
{
    @Autowired
    private EmailService emailService;

    private final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(NotificationAspect.class);

    public NotificationAspect()
    {
        log.info("****************** NotificationAspect: " + hashCode());
    }

    @AfterThrowing(pointcut="@annotation(com.creditsesame.integration.core.meta.NotifyOnFailures)",
                   throwing="ex")
    public void executeOnException(ApiExecutionException ex) throws Throwable
    {
        emailService.sendNotification();
    }
    // more code //
}
```

I put a breakpoint on the method `executeOnException` and confirmed that it is raising successfuly when an exception is thrown. The problem I have is that many instances not handled by spring are being created everytime the aspect is launched and since they aren't handled by spring all the autowired properties are null.

During the deployment when jboss starts the application I can see that initially the `NotificationAspect` contains its properties well injected. So, the issue on runtime and everytime the aspect is executed.

I have struggled a lot with this with no success. Any idea about how I can deal with this problem?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't understand your problem. Can you clarify?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis My aspect doesn't autowire its properties every time it runs. Every time the aspect runs is because a new instance of the NotificationAspect is created. But this instance is not created by spring, so the autowired properties are in null.

Comment: What is creating it? What's executing the advice? If you have a NPE, post the stacktrace.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis I configured the aspect with `@Component` so spring should handle it, but seems it works only during the app initialization. However, on runtime one instance of the aspect is created everytime instead of using the spring one.

Comment: Add a constructor and, inside it, print the stack trace. Do the same thing inside the method so we know who is calling it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could find the answer to make it work with xml approach since it was easier than using annotated beans (I had no luck to make it work with @Configurable).

I had to configure my aspect as:

```
<bean id="notificationAspect" factory-method="aspectOf" class="com.creditsesame.integration.core.aspect.NotificationAspect">
</bean>                          ^---Notice the factory-method with aspectOf()
```

On spring documentation says:

> The majority of AspectJ aspects are singleton aspects. Configuration
>   of these aspects is very easy: simply create a bean definition
>   referencing the aspect type as normal, and include the bean attribute
>   'factory-method="aspectOf"'. This ensures that Spring obtains the
>   aspect instance by asking AspectJ for it rather than trying to create
>   an instance itself.

More information can be found on section 7.8.1 and **7.8.3** on below link:

http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/aop.html#aop-aj-ltw

Thanks `Andrew Eisenberg` for guide me on the right direction and `Sotirios Delimanolis` for provide some ideas.

Answer (score 1):

At first, I was going to say that you cannot use dependency injection on an AspectJ aspect and that you must use spring aspects instead.  However, I found this old post on [Dependency injection with AspectJ and Spring](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/j-aopwork13/index.html).  Basically, you need to tell the container to use the `aspectOf()` method as the `factory-method`.  I have not tried this myself, but it looks like it might work.  You will likely need to use xml to configure this.

Comment: This is very useful. Tomorrow morning I'll try this approach. Thanks for it.

Comment: Btw, my aspect is using `@Component` and `@Aspect` annotations and it is declared as a simple class I'm not using aspect keyword, so don't know if this can work, although will check it

Comment: Hmmm...I also notice the `@Singleton` scope on this.  This *should* mean that there is only one instance of your aspect, but that is not the case according to your description.  This may mean that you are compiling using aspectj *and* using spring aspects.  I'd guess that you want to avoid the aspectj compiler and use spring aspects only.

Comment: I have defined my aspect as I posted in the answer, there is no xml additional configuration. I've based on spring documentation that said that using `@Aspect` uses the aspectj notation and `@Component` to use it with spring. The problem is that someone else is creating new instances of the aspect apart of spring

Comment: Well, the `aspectOf()` guided me through the right way, and finally I found the answer on [Spring 1.2 documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/1.2.x/reference/aspectj.html) and could make it work using xml approach. Btw, +1 for the help